# Inner product space, why does this fail (Homework Question)

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

The question is decide whether or not  $x_1^2 y_1^2 +  x_2^2 y_2^2 + x_3^2 y_3^2$ in $R^3$ is an inner product.

I though the answer was yes, but the text answer sheet says no, and I can't figure out why.

I think my mistake is when trying to check $<x,y+w>$ or $c<x,y>$ for this.

I want to say that

$<x,y+w>=x _1^2 [y_1^2 + w_1^2] + x_2^2 [y_2^2 + w_2^2] + x_3^2 [y_3^2 + w_3^2]$

$=x _1^2 y_1^2 +x _1^2  w_1^2 + x_2^2 y_2^2 + x_2^2 w_2^2 + x_3^2 y_3^2 + x_3^2 w_3^2$

$=x _1^2 y_1^2+x_2^2 y_2^2+x_3^2 y_3^2+ x _1^2  w_1^2+x_2^2 w_2^2+x_3^2 w_3^2$

$=<x,y>+<x,w>$

For a scalar 'c' in R, $c<x,y>=<cx,y>$.

I want to say it is this, but not sure:

$c(x_1^2 y_1^2 +  x_2^2 y_2^2 + x_3^2 y_3^2)$

$=c(x_1^2) y_1^2 +  c(x_2^2) y_2^2 + (cx_3^2) y_3^2$

$=<cx,y>$

I am sure the other axioms hold.

$<x,y>=<y,x>$

and of course they are squared so $<x,x>$ is greater than or equal to zero (equal if and only if x = 0)

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: The first equation you wrote is not true, it should be $<x,y+w>=x_1^2(y_1+w_1)^2+\dots$.
I think you can figure out your mistake from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\langle \lambda x,y \rangle \neq \lambda \langle x,y \rangle
$$
for so many choices of $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, $x$ and $y$; actually, the left-hand side is quadratic in $\lambda$, while the right-hand side is linear. Hence your quantity cannot be an inner product.

Comment: I think I understand. If I let $c=3$ and $x=(1,1)$ and $y=(2,2)$ Then for $c<x,y>$ I would have $3(1^2(2^2)+1^2(2^2))$ But for $<cx,y>$ I would have $3^2(2^2)+3^2(2^2)$